# Default Route With React Router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

fI currently have the following routes defined in my application:

```
/
/selectSteps
/steps
/steps/alpha
/steps/beta
/steps/charlie
```

Which could also be visualised like this:

```
- (home)
    - selectSteps
    - steps
       - alpha
       - beta
       - charlie
```

My root component looks like this:

```
  <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/select-steps" render={() => <StepSelectorContainer />} />
    <Route path="/steps" component={StepsContainer} />
```

My Steps component does this:

```
steps.map(step => (
  <Route
    path={fullPathForStep(step.uid)}
    key={shortid.generate()}
    render={() => <StepContainer step={step} />}
  />
```

This all works nicely, but I don't want `steps` to exist as route in its own right. Only its child routes should be visitable. So I'm looking to lose the `/steps` route to leave my routes as:

```
/
/selectSteps
/steps/alpha
/steps/beta
/steps/charlie
```

How should I configure my routes for this? Ideally, hitting `/steps` would *redirect* to the first child route.

Answer (score 19):

Actually, it's pretty straightforward...

Use `Redirect` component to... well, redirect.

```
<Redirect from="/steps" exact to="/steps/whatever" />
```

`exact` prop guarantees you won't be redirected from sub-route.

**Edit:** after all, `Redirect` does support `exact` (or `strict`) props. No need to wrap in `Route`. Answer updated to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks. But this will only work to replace the current route (and component). I need the container component `StepsContainer` that I'm rendering as a wrapper around the child component rendered by the child route.

Answer (score 7):

Pedr,
    I think that this will solve your problem.

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
<Route path="/select-steps" render={() => <StepSelectorContainer />} />
<Route path="/steps" component={StepsComponent} />
```

And then in your StepsComponent render method, you can do this.

```
<Switch>
{steps.map(step => (
    <Route
        path={fullPathForStep(step.uid)}
        key={shortid.generate()}
        render={() => <StepContainer step={step} />}
    />}
<Redirect from="/steps" exact to="/steps/alpha" />
</Switch>
```

What this will do is render your steps component because it the route begins with /steps.  After that is rendered, then it will render one of the nested routes based off the url.  If the url is just "/steps", then it will redirect to the initial route listed here, in this case "/steps/alpa" by rendering the redirect.  The Switch will make it so that it only renders one of the routes.

Credit to Andreyco for the redirect code.

I hope this helps.